# Mean and variance when sampling temporal rates

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, sampling, ratio

I having some trouble understanding how mean and variance are be used in sampling rates and temporal rates (per unit of time).

**Example**

If I eg. wanted to evaluate car crashes per hours driven I would like to know how evaluate the expected crashes per hours driven and how dispersed the data is. For simplicity I'm assuming event independence.

Most of the observations will have 0 crashes so it is relevant to use the rate of crashes. On a population of drivers the rate can be calculated.

$
X_i = \text{crashes},t_i = \text{hours driven}
$

$
\lambda_{pop} = E(X) = VAR(X) = \frac{\sum{X_i}}{\sum{t_i}}
$

The amount of crashes in a certain amount of time driven would then reasonably follow a Poission process. However, the Poisson process lacks the insight on how crash rates are distributed across the population.

**Sampling**

Therefore my thought is to randomly sample the population into groups and with the central limit theorem represent the distribution as a normal distribution on the population.

I think i understand sampling and ratios but struggling on the detail on how/if I should use them them in conjunction.

**General Questions**

Since I'm evaluating a ratio. Should i use the Harmonic mean for a more representative average on population/samples?

Should i use total hours driven or sample size as sampling weights?

Does the central limit theorem hold/fail with my assumptions?

**In conclusion**

I'm looking for similar problems to get inspiration on my problem and sanity checking my assumptions.